# Snowflake Query issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have query In Regarding Snowflake that

- I have 3 fields `matnr`, `ship_to` and `ship_date` in a table `zrmm` table
- I have `i_sup` field in `p_psl` table

I want to get max(ship_date) when the numeric values in i_sup matches with numeric value in ship_to

For example I will only have numerical characters in i_sup like 61701 , but in ship_to along with numerical characters i'll also have alphabetical characters as suffixes like 61701 A, 61701 B
both 61701 A, 61701B will have different ship_dates for one MATNR value

I need to compare 61701 in I_SUP with both P_PSL Values 61701 A and 61701 B in ship_to and give max(ship_date) from one among both
If 61701 A have ship_date 1/22/2024 and 61701 B have ship_date value 22/9/2023 it should give ship_date for 61701 in p_psl as 1/22/2024

I have below following columns

```
CASE
    WHEN TRY_CAST(ship_to AS NUMBER) IS NOT NULL THEN
      LPAD(CAST(CAST(PARSE_JSON('"' || ship_to || '"') AS NUMBER) AS VARCHAR), 5, '0')
    ELSE
      ship_to
  END AS ship_to, 

CASE
    WHEN TRY_CAST(i_sup AS NUMBER) IS NOT NULL THEN
      LPAD(CAST(CAST(PARSE_JSON('"' || i_sup|| '"') AS NUMBER) AS VARCHAR), 5, '0')
    ELSE
      i_sup
  END AS i_sup,
MATNR,
SHIP_DATE
```

### Example data from comment

`zrmm` table:

| MATNR | SHIP_TO | SHIP_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 68244056SD | 61701 A | 1/22/2024 |
| 68244056SD | 61701 B | 4/23/2023 |

`P_PSL` TABLE:

| I_SUPLR |
| --- |
| 61701 |

Output:

| MATNR | SHIP_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 68244056SD | 1/22/2024 |

Here 61701 in `i_sup` matches with `61701 A` and `61701 B` in `ship_to` numeric values excluding alphabetical suffix values, I mean to say numeric value matches, so I need to get maximum ship date for 61701

Comment: Hi - as you haven’t formatted much of your question it is difficult to read. Please update your question to show 1) source tables with sample data 2) the result you want to achieve (both formatted as tables) and 3) the SWL you’ve managed to write so far, formatted as code

Comment: As i mentioned in my question MATNR, SHIP_TO and SHIP_DATE are from table ZRMM
and I_SUP is from table P_PSL 

ZRMM Table:
MATNR SHIP_DATE SHIP_TO
68244056SD 61701 A 1/22/2024
68244056SD 61701 B 4/23/2023
  
P_PSL TABLE:  
I_SUPLR  
61701  

Output :
MATNR SHIP_DATE
68244056SD 1/22/2024

Here 61701 in i_sup matches with 61701 A and 61701 B in ship_to numeric values excluding alphabetical suffix values, I mean to say numeric value matches, so I wneed to get maximum ship date for 61701

please reply back

Comment: Also, please don’t provide information in comments. If you have additional/different information then please update your question to reflect this.

Comment: Okay. Could you please give solution if you understood my query

Comment: Hi - entirely up to you, of course, but you can either update you question as requested (and then I’ll try and have a look at it) or you can wait for someone else to help you with your question as it is

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

Using two CTE's to for your example data:

```
with zrmm(matnr, ship_to, ship_date) as (
    select $1, $2, to_date($3, 'YYYY/MM/DD') from values
    ('68244056SD', '61701 A', '2024/01/22'),
    ('68244056SD',  '61701 B',  '2023/04/23')
), p_psl(i_suplr) as (
    select * from values
    (61701)
)
```

We can firstly clean-up the `ship_to` to give us the field we want to join on, and then do the join. After that a trivial `max(ship_date)` and `group by` can be done.

```
select matnr
    ,max(ship_date)
from (
    select *,
        regexp_substr(ship_to, '\\d+') as ship_to_clean
    from zrmm
) as z
join p_psl as p
    on z.ship_to_clean = p.i_suplr
group by 1 order by 1;
```

gives:

| MATNR | MAX(SHIP_DATE) |
| --- | --- |
| 68244056SD | 2024-01-22 |

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps:

1. Format the SHIP_TO column from table "zrmm" to get only the first part of the value before the whitespace i.e., SPLIT_PART(SHIP_TO, ' ', 1).
2. Join both the table on new column created in Step 1 and I_SUPLR columns from table P_PSL to get only those entries in table "zrmm" which are present in table P_PSL.
3. Group by on the MATNR and find the max of SHIP_DATE

Final Query:

```
SELECT MATNR, MAX(SHIP_DATE) FROM
  (SELECT MATNR, SHIP_DATE, SPLIT_PART(SHIP_TO, ' ', 1) AS FORMATTED_SHIP_TO FROM "zrmm") as t1
JOIN
  (SELECT I_SUPLR FROM "P_PSL") as t2
ON t1.FORMATTED_SHIP_TO = t2.I_SUPLR
GROUP BY MATNR
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for writing
In ship_to there will also values as 10172AB like this where there will be no spaces between numeric and alphabetical characters
Please help
Your query worked but not fully